# One changing JavaScript variable being displayed (and updated) in multiple locations in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, dynamic

I have some javascript that is returning the word count of a text field into a 'wordcount' var.

I'd like for the 'wordcount' var (and other variables based on it) to be displayed throughout my HTML. But in a way where they can be **constantly updated** as the word count changes.

*e.g. Your current wordcount is 10. You have 5 remaining words. The current cost is £10 (£1 / Word).*

I'm relatively new to the wonders of JavaScript, but I've picked up the following from what I've read online...

1. `document.write` is frowned upon.
2. `getElementById` will only allow me to display each variable once.
3. jQuery has a `.data` functionality that stores (and updates?) data
   locally?

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Andy.

Code as requested...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Word Count Test</title>
</head>
<body onload="countnow()">


<form method="POST" name="counter">

<script language="JavaScript">
var freebie_words = 15
var base_price = 10.00
var word_price = 0.50
var wordcount = 0
var additional_words = 0

function countnow(){
var formcontent=document.counter.userscript.value
var formcontent=formcontent.split(" ")
var wordcount=formcontent.length
var freebie_remaining=freebie_words-wordcount

if (wordcount>freebie_words)
{
  additional_words=wordcount-freebie_words
} else {
  additional_words=0;
}

if (wordcount<freebie_words)
{
  cost=base_price.toFixed(2);
} else {
  cost=(base_price+(additional_words*word_price)).toFixed(2);
}

document.getElementById("freebie_words").innerHTML = freebie_words;
document.getElementById("base_price") = base_price;
document.getElementById("word_price") = word_price;
document.getElementById("wordcount") = wordcount;
document.getElementById("freebie_remaining") = freebie_remaining;
document.getElementById("cost") = cost;

}
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<textarea rows="10" name="userscript" cols="60" onkeyup="countit()"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

The base price is set to &#163;<span id='base_price'></span> for <span id='freebie_words'></span>.<br>
The base price limit is set to <span id='freebie_words'></span>.<br>
You have typed <span id='wordcount'></span> words.<br>
You have <span id='freebie_remaining'></span> free words left.<br>
That will be &#163;<span id='cost'></span>.
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually you can do this:

- Create a function that fires when your `wordcount` changes.
- Give a class to all elements (span, div, etc) that have the text/number you want to update.
- With jQuery you can then use inside your function: `$('.mychangeclass').text(wordcount);`

If you post some html I can answer adapted to your code.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the code I had as it all started falling apart because of the getElementById limitation. (2 seconds... just trying to figure out how I can newline / code. :S )

Comment: @AndyCheeseman, I cannot see your code. Can you edit the question and post it inside the question?

Comment: @AndyCheeseman, I can help editing your answer if the code is there, even unformatted

Comment: @AndyCheeseman, check this example, I changed the code a bit just to correct some things that didn't work. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/uxucG/

Comment: Much appreciated Sergio. From your example, I see you removed the word_price from being 'written' as it wasn't being used. On line 9 of the HTML, 'freebie_words' is placed again and isn't updated (as it was already on line 8). For this example, do you feel it is a case of creating as many elementId's as required? If I were to expand on this, could jQuery help reduce a growing number of redundant elementIds as you suggested? Thanks again.

Comment: @AndyCheeseman, made a update here, changed some more things(http://jsfiddle.net/uxucG/2/). You will need one elementId per line you need to change since they do unique functions. I added also one class, because you had double id's that you cannot have. Hope it helped. I will go work now but if you need more help post a new question, I'm sure you will get as good or better help :)

Comment: Thanks again Sergio. You've really helped out. It's interesting to try and get to grips with JavaScript and jQuery at the same time.